# My website is very slow. I need to improve the performance

Tags: magento-1.9, performance

**Website have Following datas :**

Product : 40000

Category : 200

Attribute Set : 583

Attribute : 2534

**Server Configuration :**

4 vCPU

16GB RAM

150GB SSD

1TB/mo bandwidth

**Media, JS, CSS is comming from CDN**

**Installed  MIRASVIT FPC extension**

**Database Catch : Redis**

My website take more than 15sec to load. Please suggest me to increse the performance

Comment: have you tried using .htaccess ?

Comment: We are using nginx server and also i done all the configuration in nginx server configuration file.

Comment: can you give me your live site url so i check what is exatctly issue is

Comment: We are using magento multi website concept.
 [retailstore](http://retailstore.bulkhouse.in), [bulkstore](http://bulkstore.bulkhouse.in)

Comment: Are you using varnish? I guess not.

Comment: No i am not using varnish.

Comment: @user3033339 : use gzip for your site, optimize images, minimum usage of extensions, dont use so  much of jquery, js, css files

Comment: Okay i will ask my server team to enable the Gzip. also i will remove jquery, js, css files.